# error , query not executing because illegal context

Tags: sybase

The below query poping this error 
The name 'name' is illegal in this context. Only constants, constant expressions, or variables allowed here.  Column names are illegal.

why?

```
 INSERT INTO UPGRADEd
         (SCRIPT_CODE,
        APP_NAME, 
        FILE_NAME,
        DATE_APPLIED,
        ACT_TYPE,
        STATUS,
          CREDENTIALS)
        VALUES
        ( 'scriptcode',
        '-appname-',
        '-filename-',
        getdate(),
       'PC',
       (select 
       case when count(1) = 1 then 'FAIL' else 'OK' end from sysobjects
       where name = ''),
       (select hostname from sysprocesses where spid = @@spid)
       )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix `insert .. values` with `insert..select`. You should put everything in select statement as below

```
INSERT INTO UPGRADEd
(  SCRIPT_CODE, APP_NAME, FILE_NAME, DATE_APPLIED,
   ACT_TYPE, STATUS, CREDENTIALS) 
select 'scriptcode','-appname-','-filename-',getdate(),
       'PC', 
       case 
       when count(1) = 1 
         then 'FAIL' 
       else 'OK' end,
       (select hostname from sysprocesses where spid = @@spid) 
from sysobjects
where name = ''
```